# Java Android WebRTC offer creation throwing error and Ice Gathering or trickling not happening

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I am using the Gradle dependency `implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039'`

This is the error:

> E/rtc:  Fatal error in:
>   gen/sdk/android/generated_metrics_jni/../../../../../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.h,
>   line 94 last system error: 0 Check failed: !env->ExceptionCheck()
>   A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11556 (network_thread
>   ), pid 11515 (est.applicatoin)

onSignalingChange: HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER is the last log call before the exception.

An SDP is created but ICE trickling is not happening i.e **OnIceGathering** or **OnIceCandidate** is not called at all.

Java Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
DataChannel mainDataChannel;
PeerConnection mainPeerConnection;
PeerConnectionFactory factory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializePeerConnectionFactory();
    initializeMyPeerConnection(); // Connection Initialization.
    startConnection(); //Getting the offer


private void initializePeerConnectionFactory() {

    PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                    .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
                    .createInitializationOptions();
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
    factory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory();
}

private void startConnection() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startConnection: Starting Connection...");
    //CreateOffer fires the request to get ICE candidates and finish the SDP. We can listen to all these events on the corresponding observers.
    mainPeerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: " + sessionDescription.description);
            mainPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateFailure: FAILED:" + s);
        }
    }, new MediaConstraints());
    Log.d(TAG, "startConnection: Start Connection end");
}

private void initializeMyPeerConnection() {
    Log.d(TAG, "initializeMyPeerConnection: Starting Initialization...");
    mainPeerConnection = createPeerConnection(factory);

    mainDataChannel = mainPeerConnection.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel", new DataChannel.Init());//Setting the data channel.
    mainDataChannel.registerObserver(new DataChannel.Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onBufferedAmountChange(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStateChange() {
            //Data channel state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChange: " + mainDataChannel.state().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got the message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "initializeMyPeerConnection: Finished Initializing.");
}

private PeerConnection createPeerConnection(PeerConnectionFactory factory) {
    List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new LinkedList<>();
    iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer());
    PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfiguration = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);
    PeerConnection.Observer pcObserver = new MyPeerConnectionObserver(TAG, mainPeerConnection);

    return factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfiguration, pcObserver);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error and solved it by adding this line

```
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform.desugaring=false
```

On `gradle.properties` file

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)